# TextBox binding: only update from source once

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I bind a TextBox to an integer with UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged.

This seems to work very fine, except when I want to change lets say 1000 to 2000.
After having deleted the 1, the binding is a bit too clever and truncates the text into one 0.

My workaround now is to explicitly call UpdateSource() after a bit of filtering, but it doesn't feel right.

Is there a correct way to solve the problem?

```
    private void OnTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsLoaded)
        {
            string text = ((TextBox)sender).Text;
            if (text.Length <= 1 || !text.StartsWith("0"))
            {
                ((TextBox)sender).GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty).UpdateSource();
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnTestLostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ((TextBox)sender).GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty).UpdateSource();                    
    }
```

Comment: Why not leave the `UpdateSourceTrigger` property as `Default` or `LostFocus`?

Comment: Because I want to update the validation and do a dirty check when entering values. It makes sense in this case, trust me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

binding to an int property has it drawbacks. if you set the value in your textbox, which can not be converted into an int, your binding will NOT work -your setter is not called, even a converter would not be called.

the most easy way is to use a string property in your viewmodel and convert the value to your int property in your model. for validation you can use IDataErrorInfo.

like Dan suggest you can set UpdateSourceTrigger to LostFocus. but this does not help when you clear your textbox ;)

Comment: I don't think this is correct. You can bind the Text property of a TextBox to an int and it will convert it (both ways) without a Converter.

Comment: @Richard : i think blindmeis doesn't say you cant bind text property to an int. He says it has drawbacks or did i misunderstood your statement ?

Comment: Perhaps I have misunderstood the explanation. I got the impression from the answer that a Binding to an int would not work because when you set the text in the textbox it would not be converted to an int in the vm, which is not the case.

Comment: Sorry, the penny has just dropped. You are talking about entering invalid values!

Comment: @Richard: yes i mean invalid values. with "good" values it would work for most types other then string